# Run Nopcommerce on mono OSX and Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mono, nopcommerce

Since mono finally supports .NET 4.5.1 on OSX, I was trying to run Nopcommerce 3.4 on mono, but when I do, I get these excpetions:

1. Could not find System.Web.Entity assembly (I solved this by delete the reference in web.config)
2. A strange error that doesn't happen on the windows platform (I'm sure my solution is running perfectly on windows/vs2013) is this message:

> System.ArgumentException An element with the same key already exists
>   in the dictionary.
>
> at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Type,System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder].Add
>   (System.Type key, IModelBinder value) [0x0007e] in
>   /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:420
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.Add (System.Type key,
>   IModelBinder value) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Nop.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start () [0x0001c] in
>   /Users/XXXXX/Documents/XXXXXXXXXX/Presentation/Nop.Web/Global.asax.cs:49
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00054] in
>   /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:230

If I run it successfully, I'll write a wiki about how to run nopcommerce on Mac :)

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance. Mono is good, but I think it still needs more time to fully support ASP.NET in the Liunx/OSX environment. I can't wait for that day!